# How to Enable the Length Field

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm trying to add columns to my table (using the GUI) in pgAdmin by right clicking Columns > select Create > select column. Under the Definition tab, I select the data type to be "char". I would like to set the length so that it does not default to 1, however the option is not enabled. How do I enable it?

I looked through the pgAdmin 4 documentation and didn't find any answers.

Answer (score 3):

You should pick the option "character varying" in 'data type' and then you have acces to "length" option, so you can choose how many

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the length of "char" type because,"char" is a 1 byte single-byte internal type and hence the length filed in pgAdmin is disabled.

Check postgres docs: [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE)